# How can I make an application and grant it admin consent from the demo account?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm developing an integration that needs admin consent, without the interaction of a user. I see that in order to give consent to an application I need to do that from the organization dashboard.

The problem is that the demo account doesn't have organization features nor the organization dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

When using `JWT Token` auth with DocuSign you need to grant consent one-time as you have mentioned, there are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Using Organizations Interface (which is an Enterprise level feature).
2. Initiate the request through the API

When going through API the user still needs to interactively grant consent through a browser however the request is initiated through DocuSign's Authentication Service.

See here for steps to take to grant consent through the API:
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html#granting-consent

In terms of the User Consent vs. Admin consent part of your question, they are actually the same thing the only difference is that the admin consent is done through the admin console and can apply to all users, the user consent is on a per user basis.

Comment: So the only way to get consent without the interaction of a user on a browser is with the Admin consent in the Organizations interface? Is there a way to access that with the free demo account?

Comment: I believe that's correct, only way to do through management console is through Org Admin... that's one of the main selling features of org admin (ie centralized management).  It's really an Enterprise feature.  According to the guide to use org admin in production your company must have SSO enabled, I don't believe DocuSign allows SSO in demo environment so that's why org admin is not available.  org guide:  https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the individual users to grant consent then you must use the organization admin panel to give consent.

To have organization administration added to your demo/developer sandbox account, please ask your DocuSign sales or technical contact to have it added.